# How do I get 3 unique items from 3 overlapping lists?

Tags: c#, list, unique

This is different to just finding unique or distinct items on each list.

I have 3 lists of reference objects, and each list can contain the same items (but can only contain each item once). I want a yes/no answer to the following question: Taking one item in each list, is there a possibility to have no duplicates?

For example:

Overall list: apple, pear, banana

List 1: apple, pear

List 2: banana

List 3: banana, apple

Result: TRUE (can choose one item from each list and have 3 unique items)

Overall list: apple, pear, banana

List 1: apple, pear

List 2: apple, pear

List 3: apple, pear

Result: FALSE (cannot choose one item from each list and have 3 unique items)

It's for a game so I need it to be efficient! Thanks in advance.

Comment: One way to approach this is to create a tree, each level has all the possibilities from one list. After that, using any tree search algorithm would work.

Comment: Thanks... I've googled trees, but I'm at a loss how this would be implemented for my case!

Comment: I think you should rephrase this _Can I choose ONE item from each list and be sure that each chosen item is distinct from the other chosen items ?_ to something like, say **Taking one item in each list, is there a possibility to have no duplicates ?**

Comment: Thanks hoang, have edited as you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

This is NP-Hard problem `Constraint satisfaction problem` [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem).
In other words, you have group {a,b,c,d} and you want to find `(a or b) and (b or c) and...`

But, if you know all the possible options ahead you can create a list\dictionary of the values (hashed values for smaller list) and just check the list in runtime.

If not you can use one of the CSP solving algorithms.

Comment: I do know the 3 lists' contents ahead of time (I create all 3 lists, then compare). However, "just create a list/dictionary and check the list" is not particularly helpful!

Comment: If this isn't 'particularly helpful', what exactly have you tried so far?  Right now, it seems like you're looking for someone to do your homework for you.

Comment: what do you mean not helpful? Do you want the code? Creating dictionary is simple, hashing is also simple...

Comment: Yes, I can create a dictionary, I just need a nudge towards an actual application of that idea - not the whole code. Is the answer here to check every single combination? If so, that doesn't strike me as very efficient...

Comment: The algorithm goes something like this:
Calculate and save (once for the first time only) all the options
h = hash({a,b},{b,c},{c})
save in dictionary Dict<-(h,True)
In run time you need to calculate the hash of the state and check the value in your dictionary.

Comment: Maybe I misspoke when I said I know the lists' contents ahead of time. I mean I create all 3 lists completely before doing the check - but the lists are created from scratch again and again.

Answer (score 0):

[image: sets]

Let's says you've got list `α`, `β` and `ɣ`.

Let `ABC = α ∩ β ∩ ɣ`
Let `AB = α ∩ β \ ABC`
Let `AC = α ∩ ɣ \ ABC`
Let `BC = β ∩ ɣ \ ABC`
Let `A = α \ (β ∪ ɣ)`
Let `B = β \ (α ∪ ɣ)`
Let `C = ɣ \ (α ∪ β)`

Let |X| be the cardinality of set X.

return true if and only if `|A| + |B| + |C| + |AB| + |AC| + |BC| + |ABC| >= 3`

Example implementation :

```
void Main()
{
    var alpha = new List<string> { "apple", "pear", };
    var beta = new List<string> { "banana", };
    var gamma = new List<string> { "banana", "apple", };

    Console.WriteLine(Compute(alpha, beta, gamma));
    Console.WriteLine(ComputeWithSets(alpha, beta, gamma));

    alpha = new List<string> { "apple", "pear", };
    beta = new List<string> { "apple", "pear", };
    gamma = new List<string> { "apple", "pear", };

    Console.WriteLine(Compute(alpha, beta, gamma));
    Console.WriteLine(ComputeWithSets(alpha, beta, gamma));

    alpha = new List<string> { "apple", "pear", "banana", };
    beta = new List<string> { "apple", "pear", "banana", };
    gamma = new List<string> { "apple", "pear", "banana", };

    Console.WriteLine(Compute(alpha, beta, gamma));
    Console.WriteLine(ComputeWithSets(alpha, beta, gamma));
}

bool Compute(List<string> alpha, List<string> beta, List<string> gamma)
{
    if (alpha.Count == 0) return false;
    if (beta.Count == 0) return false;
    if (gamma.Count == 0) return false;

    foreach (var a in alpha)
        foreach (var b in beta)
            if (a != b)
                foreach (var c in gamma)
                    if (c != a && c != b)
                    {
                        Console.Write(string.Format("{0},{1},{2} =>", a, b, c));
                        return true;    
                    }
    return false;
}

bool ComputeWithSets(List<string> alpha, List<string> beta, List<string> gamma)
{
    var abc = alpha.Intersect(beta.Intersect(gamma));
    var abcCardinality = abc.Count();

    var count = abcCardinality;
    if (count >= 3) return true;

    var ab = alpha.Intersect(beta).Except(abc);
    count += ab.Count();
    if (count >= 3) return true;

    var bc = beta.Intersect(gamma).Except(abc);
    count += bc.Count();
    if (count >= 3) return true;

    var ac = alpha.Intersect(gamma).Except(abc);
    count += ac.Count();
    if (count >= 3) return true;

    var a = alpha.Except(ab).Except(ac).Except(abc);
    count += a.Count();
    if (count >= 3) return true;

    var b = beta.Except(ab).Except(bc).Except(abc);
    count += b.Count();
    if (count >= 3) return true;

    var c = gamma.Except(ac).Except(bc).Except(abc);
    count += c.Count();
    if (count >= 3) return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Not sure that's correct in my case: for example, all three lists could be identical and contain three items - that would mean A, B and C in your illustration would be non-existent, but for my purposes the answer should be TRUE.

Comment: Updated my answer. If all three lists are identical and contain three items, you'll have |ABC| = 3 hence true.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it as follows:

You take the first item in your overall list and then check each of your 3 "target" lists to see which it occurs in. Store these check results in a 3 element array (1 element for each of your target lists) - say 0 for doesn't occur and 1 for does occur.
Then do this again for the 2nd item in your overall list and so on.
So you will end up with a "check list" of 3 element arrays (the list length being equal to the number of items on your overall array.
Then you sum up the first element of every array in your check list, the second element and the third element. As long as the each sum is greater than 0 your test passes.

e.g. for your first example 
Overall list : apple, pear, banana

```
Check results:
Item 1 (apple)  : 1 0 1 (apple occurs in list 1 and 3)
Item 2 (pear)   : 1 0 0 
Item 3 (banana) : 0 1 1
Total             2 1 2 (result is a pass)
```

Your second example will fail because you will have two check arrays of 1 1 0 and when you add up the third element from each these arrays you will get 0.

I think this can be easily extended to as many target lists as you want - if you have n lists, your check arrays will each contain n elements.